Arduino IDE: how to redefine constant defined in standard library?
I am trying to redefine WEBSOCKETS_TCP_TIMEOUT constant in this library: [https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets]. But I do not want to change library, I would like to do it in my code.
Constant defined in WebSocket.h:
#ifndef WEBSOCKETS_TCP_TIMEOUT
#define WEBSOCKETS_TCP_TIMEOUT (5000)
#endif

But when I define the same constant in my code - library does not pick it up, stays with its unchanged value, although within my own code I see my desired value. Here is the sample of my code:
#define WEBSOCKETS_TCP_TIMEOUT (10)
#include <WebSocketsServer.h

void setup() 
{
...
Serial.printf("WS Timeout: %d\r\n", WEBSOCKETS_TCP_TIMEOUT);
}

It prints my desired value, but library operates with old value... If I put #include before my #define - the same. But if I remove my define and change definition in WebSocket.h (which I do not want to do) - it prints correct value and operated with new value.
What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to re-refine constant defined in standard library?

You need to make sure that the library is compiled using this value. If WebSockets.cpp "saw" 5000 at the time it was compiled, nothing you do later is going to change that. It's in the object file now. You don't have to change the library's source code, but you must ensure that the macro is defined at the time that the library is built, for example by passing it to the compiler with -DWEBSOCKETS_TCP_TIMEOUT=10 (though 10ms is a very short timeout).
With the Arduino compiler, this would generally be done with build-properties, for example:
arduino-cli compile --build-properties="build.extra_flags=-DWEBSOCKETS_TCP_TIMEOUT=10" ...

Just keep in mind, this needs to be the command that compiles the library you want. Once the library is built, you cannot change this setting.

Thank you!
How I can I pass it to compiler?
"by passing it to the compiler with -DWEBSOCKETS_TCP_TIMEOUT=10"
I am using Arduino IDE 2.*, I did not see options to edit command-line parameters for compiler...

I've never used that IDE. The most recent forum post from the Arduino Team I could find on the subject suggests using the command line for these kinds of features. https://forum.arduino.cc/t/ide-2-x-suggestions/1063723  I don't see any more up-to-date information in their docs.
